# How do I get the details of the user who deleted a few builds of a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

I know that a build had run for a Jenkins job (I received an e-mail with the results and the build number #9).

But, when I open Jenkins to check the Build History, the build in question (Build #9) is not there. When I try to trigger a new build, it is counted as Build #10. So, somebody must have deleted Build #9 manually from Jenkins (my guess).

If yes, how do I get the details of the user who deleted that build?

Is there a log I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Jenkins Audit Trail Plugin installed? 
 You can use it to keep an audit of "most actions with significant effect such as creating/configuring/deleting jobs and views or delete/save-forever/start a build".

So it looks like the example you gave of deleting a build would be covered.

See  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Audit+Trail+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

The [Job Configuration History](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jobConfigHistory) plugin will keep track of all changes (delta+user)  AND let you roll back, but only after you install it.